# Language Tracking with Server-Side Google Analytics

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics

I've ported the google analytics server side code over into my Python GAE application. Everything is working great, except for language tracking. I'm wondering if anyone here who has used google analytics on the server side has had success tracking languages.

The relevant bit of code is:

```
  utm_url = utm_gif_location + "?" + \
        "utmwv=" + GA_VERSION + \
        "&utmn=" + str(randint(0, 0x7fffffff)) + \
        "&utmhn=" + urllib.quote(domain) + \
        "&utmsr=" + '-' + \
        "&utme=" + '-' + \
        "&utmr=" + urllib.quote(document_referer) + \
        "&utmp=" + path + \
        "&utmac=" + GA_ACCOUNT + \
        "&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B" + \
        "&utmvid=" + visitor_id + \
        "&utmip=" + ip

  headers = {
    'User-Agent': req.get('ua'),
    'Accept-Language': req.get('lang')
    }
  httpresp = urlfetch.fetch(
    url      = utm_url,
    method   = urlfetch.GET,
    headers =  headers
    )

  if httpresp.status_code == 200:
    logging.info("GA success: %s(%s)\n%s" % (utm_url, headers, httpresp.headers) )
  else:
    logging.warning("GA fail: %s %d" % (utm_url, httpresp.status_code) )
```

And here is a little debugging output which shows that I'm sending the Accept-Language header:

```
GA success: http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.4sh&utmn=1306014991&utmhn=XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com&utmsr=-&utme=-&utmr=-&utmp=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&utmac=MO-XXXXX-XX&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B&utmvid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&utmip=XXX.XXX.XX.XX({'Accept-Language': u'en-us', 'User-Agent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405'})
{'content-length': '35', 'x-google-cache-control': 'remote-fetch', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'age': '93451', 'expires': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2000 11:43:00 GMT', 'server': 'GFE/2.0', 'last-modified': 'Wed, 21 Jan 2004 19:51:30 GMT', 'via': 'HTTP/1.1 GWA', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate', 'date': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2012 16:25:04 GMT', 'content-type': 'image/gif'}
```

(I've XXXX'd stuff to protect the innocent).

As I said, everything is working great (locations, hit count, user agent), except languages. They are all being counted as "not set".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language attribute that Google Analytics tracks isn't from headers.

Rather, it's passed directly in the URL request to `__utm.gif` as the `utmul` attribute.

So, my computer sets `utmul=en-us`, using the navigator.language or navigator.browserLanguage attributes (which it seems like it makes lower case.)

In your case, that means you just need to add this line to your __utm.gif constructions:

```
"&utmul=" +  req.get('lang')
```

Comment: Fascinating! The sample code google provides doesn't use that attribute. It uses the headers. I've added that flag as you suggested, and now we'll wait 24 hours to see if it helps!

Comment: Great news. This did, in fact, get the language data through to GA.